Strapi load env variables in a custom config file
I'm trying to load my env variables directly in a custom config file that i use for rabbitmq. Here's my custom config that is found in config/rabbitmq.ts
import amqp, { Channel, Connection, Options } from 'amqplib';
import { Topic, Message } from './topics';

let connection: Connection | null = null;
let channel: Channel | null = null;

const RabbitMQClient = (strapi) => {
  const { url, queue, reconnectInterval } = strapi.config.get('plugin.rabbitmq');

  // code omitted 

  return {
    connect,
    sendMessageToQueue,
  };
};

export default RabbitMQClient;

And here is what I added in my config/plugin.ts
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "strapi-provider-cloudflare-r2",
      providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: env("R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
        secretAccessKey: env("R2_ACCESS_SECRET"),
        endpoint: env("R2_ENDPOINT"),
        params: {
          Bucket: env("R2_BUCKET"),
        },
        /**
         * Set this Option to store the CDN URL of your files and not the R2 endpoint URL in your DB.
         * Can be used in Cloudflare R2 with Domain-Access or Public URL: https://pub-<YOUR_PULIC_BUCKET_ID>.r2.dev
         * This option is required to upload files larger than 5MB, and is highly recommended to be set.
         * Check the cloudflare docs for the setup: https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/data-access/public-buckets/#enable-public-access-for-your-bucket
         */
        cloudflarePublicAccessUrl: env("R2_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL"),
        /**
         * Sets if all assets should be uploaded in the root dir regardless the strapi folder.
         * It is useful because strapi sets folder names with numbers, not by user's input folder name
         * By default it is false
         */
        pool: false,
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
  transformer: {
    enabled: true,
    config: {
      responseTransforms: {
        removeAttributesKey: true,
        removeDataKey: true,
      },
    }
  },
  rabbitmq: {
    url: env('RABBITMQ_URL'),
    queue: env('RABBITMQ_INGEST_QUEUE'),
    reconnectInterval: env('RECONNECT_INTERVAL', 3000),
  },
});

And I pass the strapi object in my strapi's bootstrap method:
import RabbitMQClient from "../config/rabbitmq";

export default {
  /**
   * An asynchronous register function that runs before
   * your application is initialized.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to extend code.
   */
  register(/*{ strapi }*/) {},

  /**
   * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
   * your application gets started.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
   * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
   */
  async bootstrap{ strapi }) {
    const rabbitMQClient = RabbitMQClient(strapi);
    rabbitMQClient.connect();
  }
};

Unfortunately for me, it seems that strapi is unable to get these variables, because I get the following error:
Error: Could not load js config file C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\cms\dist\config\rabbitmq.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') 

My question is is there a better way to do this? To pass env variables to my custom config?

You can use process.env.[variable-name] to access environment variables. However, you should create a custom RabbitMQ plugin and pass the configuration into the plugin through the config/plugin.ts file. Correct the configuration in the config/plugin.ts file:
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
      ...
      ,
      rabbitmq: {
        enabled: true,
        config: {
          url: env('RABBITMQ_URL'),
          queue: env('RABBITMQ_INGEST_QUEUE'),
          reconnectInterval: env('RECONNECT_INTERVAL', 3000),
        },
        resolve: './src/plugins/rabbitmq',
      },
    });

Access config in plugin:
strapi.plugin('rabbitmq').config('url') //or
strapi.config.get('rabbitmq.url')

Reference: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/plugins/server-api#configuration
